# AngularJS cannot load ng-view inti index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to setup a one page application with AngularJS.
I am using Node with Express, and I have an apache server used as a middleware, if that matters.
My index.html page loads well but no view is loaded inside the ng-view.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="public/img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="public/img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angularjs/1.4.7/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angularjs/1.4.7/js/angular-base64.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angularjs/1.4.7/js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/lodash.js/4.16.4/js/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/1.11.3/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module('lispCDpoc', ['ngRoute']);

      myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        console.log('oui');
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/test.html',
            controller: 'testController'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
      });

      myApp.controller('testController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Message for my test page';
      });
    </script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LISP Monitoring POC</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img                        src="public/img/sg_logo_small.png" class="sg-logo"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="#releasenote">Release Note</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <img class="logo-lisp" src="public/img/lisp2.png">
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I can't find the reason why my index.html page loads but it does not insert the test.html code

```
<div>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to declare your app module in your main template.

```
  <body ng-app="lispCDpoc">
    <div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img                        src="public/img/sg_logo_small.png" class="sg-logo"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="#releasenote">Release Note</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <img class="logo-lisp" src="public/img/lisp2.png">
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here's a working Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/HlYxdCsLzfCNCY1dq7vp?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, seems better now since I see a change in the web page structure : 
Before I had the
    <div ng-view></div>
now I have 
    <!-- ngView:  -->

But still not the code inside the test.html page... It is indeed in the 'pages' folder tho

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to have undertsood you

Comment: Ok np! Let me some minutes to make you a working example

Comment: @capitaineballs Edited my answer with Plunkr link :)

Comment: ok i'll take a look at home (leaving soon :) ) since it is not accessible at work.
After some testings on my side, Angular is actually rerouting me. For example when I change the "otherwise" statement to "redirectTo: '/ok', if reroutes me to mywebsite/#/ok as long as I type something after the latest "/". So it cannt access the .html or something like this, I guess

Comment: Concerning your last point, I don't know. If you've set `otherwise redirect to /`, it should redirect your routing to `testController`. Anyway, this part is working, tell me if you have other questions concerning this point (ng-view not working). The rest can be asked in another question

Comment: Got it working. Console told me it could not find the test.html indeed. After some changes, found the right way to write the path. I'll make sure to look at your plunkr anyway, I will sure help me understanding better.
Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Oh so it was a path matter, I wasn't thinking about this point ^^ Glad it works now. But for the main issue, remember that if you want your AngularJS app working, you have to init the app in script part, but in the view part too